# Bulk load aborted with some files not yet loaded

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bulk-load

I am doing bulk load in Hbase But getting error while loading Hfiles.

```
11:02:49.909 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles - -------------------------------------------------
Bulk load aborted with some files not yet loaded:
-------------------------------------------------
  hdfs://10.13.10.19:8020/madhuri/userOutput/personalDetails/6255a0ffd4e14f70ad2146bb756f004c

java.io.IOException: Retry attempted 10 times without completing, bailing out
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles.performBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:420)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:256)
at com.clouds.dbtest.test.HbaseBulkLoad.doBulkLoad(HbaseBulkLoad.java:26)
at com.clouds.dbtest.test.HBaseBulkLoadDriver.run(HBaseBulkLoadDriver.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
at com.clouds.dbtest.test.HBaseBulkLoadDriver.main(HBaseBulkLoadDriver.java:41)
```

I have taken code from [link](https://www.rswebsols.com/tutorials/programming/bulk-load-big-data-hadoop-hbase-table).